# High Sierra missing openssl manpages

Tags: macos, high-sierra, openssl

Using the default manpage paths (via /private/etc/man.conf), the openssl(1) and related pages (i.e. x509(1), req(1), ca(1), etc.) are missing.

Has anyone discovered if these were placed in a different location or if left out altogether?

Comment: Looking at the contents of the InstallESD.dmg from macOS 10.13, those man pages are missing.

Answer (score 1):

These manpages are missing for me as well on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65). I also noted that some manpages are outdated and incomplete (for example `pmset` is from 2012, lacking some details).

However I do have some manpages via MacPorts (e.g. OpenSSL(1)).

I have these paths in `/private/etc/man.conf`:

```
MANPATH /usr/share/man
MANPATH /usr/local/share/man
MANPATH /usr/X11/man
```

(the latter two are non-existent), and these in `/private/etc/manpaths`:

```
/usr/share/man
/usr/local/share/man
```

(the latter again non-existent).